# Split 1 ArrayList into multiple ones based on condition

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a big ArrayList containing strings. I want to split it, based on a condition that an element meets. For example, it could be the string length if ArrayList contained String. What is the most efficient (not the easiest) way to do that ?

```
['a', 'bc', 'defe', 'dsa', 'bb']
```

after would result to :

```
['a'], ['bc', 'bb'], ['dsa'], ['defe']
```

Comment: Without closer specifying the condition: there are no optimizations possible, you'll have to settle with brute-force. You could optimize the respective data-structures a bit, but the matching itself can't be optimized without knowing by what attribute it is done.

Comment: What's is the condition? Why are `bc` and `bb` grouped together but `dsa` and `defe` aren't?

Comment: @ike_love It follows the example given in question text: They are grouped by string *length*.

Answer (score 3):

It's easy and fairly efficient to do it using Java 8 streams:

```java
Collection<List<String>> output = input.stream()
                                       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::length))
                                       .values();
```

If you run it with this input:

```java
List<String> input = Arrays.asList("a", "bc", "defe", "dsa", "bb");
```

You will get this output:

```
[[a], [bc, bb], [dsa], [defe]]
```

A non-stream version would do the same thing, i.e. build a `Map<K, List<V>>` where `V` is your value type (e.g. `String` in your case), and `K` is the type of the grouping value (e.g. `Integer` for the *length*).

Doing it yourself (like shown in [answer by palako](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40688278/5221149)) might be slightly more efficient at runtime, but likely not in any way that matters.

Staying with Java 8, that would be this:

```java
Map<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
for (String value : input)
    map.computeIfAbsent(value.length(), ArrayList::new).add(value);
Collection<List<String>> output = map.values();
```

For earlier versions of Java, you can't use `computeIfAbsent()`, so:

```java
Map<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
for (String value : input) {
    Integer length = Integer.valueOf(value.length()); // box only once
    List<String> list = map.get(length);
    if (list == null)
        map.put(length, list = new ArrayList<String>());
    list.add(value);
}
Collection<List<String>> output = map.values();
```

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way is to iterate the original list just once. What you do is you create buckets and add to those buckets.

```
public class Q1 {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] original = {"a","bc","defe","dsa","bb"};

        List<String> originalValues = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(original));
        Map<Integer, List<String>> orderedValues = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();

        Iterator<String> it = originalValues.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String currentElement = it.next();
            int length = currentElement.length();
            if(!orderedValues.containsKey(length)) {
                orderedValues.put(length, new ArrayList<String>());
            }
            orderedValues.get(length).add(currentElement);
        }
        System.out.println(orderedValues.values());
    }
}
```

You might be tempted to use an array of arrays instead of a Map, and use the size of the string as the index to the array position, but then you need to watch out for a case where you don't have strings of a certain length. Imagine a case where you only have a string in the original list, but it has 100 characters. You would have 99 empty positions and one string in the array at position 100.

Comment: In Java 8, you can replace `get(length)` with `computeIfAbsent(length, ArrayList::new)`, eliminating the `if` statement. --- Also, why are you using an Iterator `while` loop instead of the simpler enhanced `for` loop? --- Combined, that reduces your loop to `for (String value : originalValues) { orderedValues.computeIfAbsent(value.length(), ArrayList::new).add(value); }`

Comment: I was trying to make it more universal and compatible, but your tips in the comment will be helpful if he is implementing in Java 8, thanks!